# Add Tags to Virtual Machine Resource in an Environment from Config Script

Tags: azure-devops, tags, virtual-machine, environment

Is there a way to add tags when adding a VM Resource to an Environment when using the configuration script? I know that you can do it through the interactive prompts when running the script manually, but I want to automate the configuration process. I'm basically looking for a similar functionality as what's available when configuring deployment groups where you can specify the tags as an argument to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops#adding-and-managing-tags) do not mention this related info:

> You can add tags to the VM as part of the interactive PS registration
>   script. You can also add or remove tags from the resource view by
>   clicking on ... at the end of each VM resource on the Resources tab.

However, since it's similar to configure build agent in Azure DevOps. When you check the code of configuration script.

It's also just using `.\config.cmd` command

```
.\config.cmd --environment --environmentname "TEST" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://xxx.visualstudio.com/' --projectname 'MyFirstProject' --auth PAT --token 6ct2r2pb7cd3cafuxi4lp5tfpkug7j6gg2yk------qgkqeaa; Remove-Item $agentZip;
```

So we could simply run `.\config.cmd --help` to check the help info of this command in powershell.

[image]

After go though the detail info, it only mention how to add a deploygroup tag through an option. Not any info related to tag of vm resource in environment.

I'm afraid this is not available to automate add  a tag in  configuration  script.